# transpose square matrix with pointer in C. wrong output

Tags: c, matrix

The goal is to print the transpose of the 'Matrix'.

To create square matrix, I got 'row' from the keyboard. 
row is same with column so I only declared 'row'.

the problem I need help is right below ↓

```
/*input*/
5 4 1
9 0 1
6 5 7

/*output I want*/
5 9 6
4 0 5 
1 1 7

/*wrong output I get*/
0 4 -30838770
0 7 2
0 5 7
```

And here is my code. Matrix in each function must be called by reference. I also want to know if I got it right.

```
//code start 

int Generate(int row, int (*Matrix)[row])
{
    srand(time(NULL)); //make random number 

    int i, j;
    printf("Matrix = "); 
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(j=0; j<row; j++){
            Matrix[i][j] = (rand() % 10); //insert random number from 0 to 10
            printf("%d ", Matrix[i][j]); //print matrix before transposing
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
    return 0;
}

void Transpose(int row, int (*Matrix)[row])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(j=0; j<row; j++){
            int transpose[i][j];
            transpose[i][j] = Matrix[j][i]; 
            printf("%d ", transpose[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
} 

int main() {

    int input; //for switch case
    int row = 0; //row has to be 2 or 3
    int Matrix[row][row]; //2d array. largest index should be Matrix [row-1][row-1]

    while(1){ 

    scanf("%d", &input);

        switch(input){
            case 1: // Generate random square matrix
                scanf("%d", &row); //insert row
                Generate(row, Matrix); 
                break;
            case 2: //transpose matrix
                Transpose(row, Matrix);
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}

//code end
```

I'm new to this community so I'm not sure I gave you all the information needed.

Please let me know the lines you don't understand because I really want to get this code work.

I'm waiting for your help!

Comment: You're creating a new matrix on each iteration of the inner-loop of your `transpose()`, which is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Just improve the user interaction of your program. I'm not getting any errorneous output like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is trying to `print` the transpose, so you don't need to store anything. remove all the stuff with `transpose[i][j]`, and just print `Matrix[j][i]`. As pointed out in the comments, you are allocating (on the stack) a new matrix of shape *ixj* at each iteration, which makes no sense.

Comment: Run it and you'll get a **Segmentation fault**, when the ```row > 3```.

Comment: @Lucas Why would the row be greater than 3?

Comment: Why would not be? It's not what OP is asking. According to him, it should be 2 or 3, that's okay. But what if ```row > 3```?

Comment: @Lucas the loop variables go to `row`. What exactly are you on about?

Comment: Let's [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/216179/transpose-of-square-matrices?tab=general) here.